# Writing linear programs in LaTeX with \systeme package

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays, systeme

I'm trying to use LaTeX to present some longer linear programs for an optimization problem. Using the `\systeme` package allows me to automatically align the variables and inequalities with each other, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to properly format the text to the left. Ideally, the text "min" should be directly to the left of the objective function (first line), and the text "s.t." should be directly to the left of the first constraint (first inequality). Included below is some example code.

If anyone can recommend how to align the text "s.t." to the top of its box in the array, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\\[  
\begin{array}{lc}  
min & -0.3x_1-0.7x_2-1.1x_3+0.08x_4-0.32x_5-0.72x_6+1.2x_7+0.8x_8 \\  
s.t. &  
\sysdelim..  
\systeme[][:]{0.1x_1 - 0.2x_2 \geq 0 :  
            0.25x_4 - 0.05x_5 \geq 0 :  
            -0.4x_1 - 0.4x_2 + 0.6x_3 \geq 0 :  
            -0.2x_4 - 0.2x_5 +0.8x_6 \geq 0 :  
            -x_3 - x_6 +0.6x_7 + 0.3x_8 \geq 0 :  
            -x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4-x_5-x_6 \geq -3000 :  
            x_1+x_2+x_3 \geq 1000 :  
            -x_1-x_2-x_3 \geq -1500 :  
            0.9x_4+0.9x_5+0.9x_6 \geq 1000 :  
            -0.9x_4-0.9x_5-0.9x_6 \geq -2000 :  
            -x_7-x_8 \geq -2000}\\  
& \vec{x} \geq \vec{0}  
\end{array}  
\\]  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\systeme` has no provision for changing the vertical alignment with respect to the context: it always use `\vcenter`.

You can (locally or globally) patch it to use `\vtop` (for top alignment) or `\vbox` (for bottom alignment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\patchsysteme[1]{%
  \xpatchcmd{\SYS@systeme@iii}{\vcenter}{#1}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[  
\begin{array}{lc}
\min & -0.3x_1-0.7x_2-1.1x_3+0.08x_4-0.32x_5-0.72x_6+1.2x_7+0.8x_8 \\[2ex]
\text{s.t.} &
  \patchsysteme{\vtop}
  \sysdelim..  
  \systeme[][:]{0.1x_1 - 0.2x_2 \geq 0 :  
            0.25x_4 - 0.05x_5 \geq 0 :  
            -0.4x_1 - 0.4x_2 + 0.6x_3 \geq 0 :  
            -0.2x_4 - 0.2x_5 +0.8x_6 \geq 0 :  
            -x_3 - x_6 +0.6x_7 + 0.3x_8 \geq 0 :  
            -x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4-x_5-x_6 \geq -3000 :  
            x_1+x_2+x_3 \geq 1000 :  
            -x_1-x_2-x_3 \geq -1500 :  
            0.9x_4+0.9x_5+0.9x_6 \geq 1000 :  
            -0.9x_4-0.9x_5-0.9x_6 \geq -2000 :  
            -x_7-x_8 \geq -2000}\\
& \vec{x} \geq \vec{0}
\end{array}  
\]  

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd use `l` alignment for the second column.

---

If you only need top alignment, here is a definition for `\systeme*` that provides it, while the unadorned `\systeme` continues to do center alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\SYS@systeme@iii}{\vcenter}{\systeme@center@top}{}{}%
\let\systeme@original\systeme
\let\systeme@center@top\vcenter
\renewcommand{\systeme}{%
  \begingroup
  \@ifstar{\systeme@top}{\systeme@make}%
}
\newcommand{\systeme@top}{%
  \let\systeme@center@top\vtop
  \systeme@make
}
\def\systeme@make#1#{%
  \def\systeme@options{#1}%
  \systeme@@make
}
\def\systeme@@make#1{%
  \expandafter\systeme@original\systeme@options{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[  
\begin{array}{lc}
\min & -0.3x_1-0.7x_2-1.1x_3+0.08x_4-0.32x_5-0.72x_6+1.2x_7+0.8x_8 \\[2ex]
\text{s.t.} &
  \sysdelim..  
  \systeme*[][:]{0.1x_1 - 0.2x_2 \geq 0 :  
            0.25x_4 - 0.05x_5 \geq 0 :  
            -0.4x_1 - 0.4x_2 + 0.6x_3 \geq 0 :  
            -0.2x_4 - 0.2x_5 +0.8x_6 \geq 0 :  
            -x_3 - x_6 +0.6x_7 + 0.3x_8 \geq 0 :  
            -x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4-x_5-x_6 \geq -3000 :  
            x_1+x_2+x_3 \geq 1000 :  
            -x_1-x_2-x_3 \geq -1500 :  
            0.9x_4+0.9x_5+0.9x_6 \geq 1000 :  
            -0.9x_4-0.9x_5-0.9x_6 \geq -2000 :  
            -x_7-x_8 \geq -2000}\\
& \vec{x} \geq \vec{0}
\end{array}  
\]  

\end{document}
```